# ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item

Tags: latex, pdflatex

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphics} 
\usepackage {epsfig}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\linespread{1.4}

\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.4in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0.3in}    % between header and text
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in} % height of main text
\setlength{\textwidth}{6in}    % width of text
%\setlength{\leftmargin}{-0.6in}
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.75in} % odd page left margin
%\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.75in} % even page left margin
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.4in}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.4in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{0.4in}


\begin{document}
\renewcommand\bibname{References}

\begin{titlepage}
\input{TitlePage}
\end{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
%\tableofcontents 

\chapter*{
    \begin{center}
    {Abstract}
    \end{center}
}
\begin{quotation}
\paragraph{} 

Bank are providing mobile application to their customer. We are developing 
banking application using Location Based Encryption. As compare to current 
banking application which are location independent,



\\
\textbf{Keywords:} 
Enter Keyword here.......
\end{quotation}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear all fields
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{}
\renewcommand\headrule{}
\rhead{PROJECT NAME}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{P.E.O COLLEGE}
\input{intro}
%\input{Literature_Survey}
\input{table}
%\input{problmstmt}
\input{scope}
%\input{future}
\input{conclusion}
\input{ref}
\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

I have this latex code. But when I try to compile it it gives me an error saying :

> ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.See the
>   LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H  for
>   immediate help....

This error is on line:

```
\end{quotation}
```

Why am I getting this error? I haven't added any `\item` on the line where I'm getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

The `\paragraph` and `\\` instructions in the `quotation` do not make much sense.  I guess that you meant something like this:

```
\begin{quotation}

\noindent
Banks are providing mobile applications to their customer.  We are developing a
banking application using \emph{Location Based Encryption}.  Compared to current 
banking applications, which are location independent, \ldots

\paragraph{Keywords:} bank, application, encryption, location, mobile.

\end{quotation}
```